# i have a problem with changing background color on nonfiction its changing just the icon color on leading or background icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

I'm expecting to pop a notification with background specified:

```
const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,

      colorized: true,

      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
      color: Colors.red, // Set background color here
    );


    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().show(
      0,
      'Notification Title',
      'Notification Body',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]